# Are factors corresponding to a sub-$\sigma$-algebra unique?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mathcal B$ be its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $X$ and $T:X\to X$ me an invertible measure preserving transformation.
Let $U_T:L^2(X, \mu)\to L^2(X, \mu)$ be the associated Koopman operator.
Let $\mathcal A$ be the smallest sub-$\sigma$-algebra on $X$ with respect to which all the eigenfunctions of $U_T$ are measurable.
Theorem 6.10 in Einsiedler and Ward's *Ergodic Theory with a View Towards Number Theory* [EW] states the following:

> **Theorem.** The factor of $(X, \mathcal B, \mu, T)$ corresponding to $\mathcal A$ is the largest factor of $(X, \mathcal B, \mu, T)$ which is isoomorphic to a rotation on some compact abelian group.

**I do not follow** why are we allowed to use the definite article "the" when asking for a factor corresponding to the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$.

I ask this question because the following theorem [EW, Theorem 6.5] only guarantees 'a' factor.

> **Theorem.** Let $(X, \mathcal B, \mu, T)$ be a measure preserving system, where $X$ is a compact metric space and $\mathcal B$ is its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
>   Let $\mathcal A$ be a $T$-invariant sub-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal B$.
>   Then there is a measure preserving system $(Y, \mathcal B_Y, \nu, S)$, where $Y$ is a compact metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B_Y$, and a factor map $\phi:X\to Y$ with $\mathcal A=\phi^{-1}(\mathcal B_Y)\pmod \mu$.

Is is perhaps true that any two factors corresponding to a given sub-$\sigma$-algerba $\mathcal A$ are isomorphic?

P.S. I have changed the wording of the theorems I have taken from [EW]. Also, in [EW] the theorems are stated for Borel probability spaces, which are more general than compact metric spaces.

Comment: Lemma $5.25$ from EW gives a map between two such factors. I think you can prove some quasi-uniqueness statement about two maps arising from this lemma.

Comment: I think your comment solves my issue. Can you frame it as an answer so that I can accept? Thanks.

Comment: Please read chapter $7$ and answer my question =D

Comment: @Unpud I don't follow. Your question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989042/clarification-on-a-proof-of-roths-theorem

Comment: Have you got to this part of EW yet? I was wondering if you ran into this issue.

Comment: I was reading the proof of Roth's theorem when I had to go back and read some material from Chapter 6. It will take me some time to start with the proof again since I need to first understand the basics about factors. In case I figure it out I will sure post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma $5.25$ from EW gives a map between two such factors. I think you can prove some quasi-uniqueness statement about two maps arising from this lemma.